# Go to previous user input is user inputs specified string

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I have a CLI which asks the users to input several parameters using `raw_input`. Is there a way to go back to the previous user input without having to repeat the entire programme? I don't need code to restart the entire programme, but the option to go over previous user inputs at the request of the user.

```
fruit = ["apples","bananas","pears"]

inputs = []

for count,a in zip(range(3),fruit):
    query = raw_input("Do you like "+a+"?")
    inputs.append(query)

    if [any(n)=='back' for n in inputs[1::]]:
         a = fruit[count-1]
```

This asks the user if they like apples, bananas and pears. If they type in "back" the previous user input should be print on the CL.

So,

```
>>> Do you like apples? y
>>> Do you like bananas?back
>>> Do you like apples? n
>>> Do you like bananas? y
```

My expected outcome is if the user types in `"back"` for any input, the previous input will be repeated and the corresponding element in `inputs` should be updated. The option to go back should only occur after the user inputs the first input.

My code will store the previous element in `fruits` if the user types `back`, but I don't know how to use this to update the `raw_input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work...

```
fruit = ['apples', 'bananas', 'pears']
inputs = []

index = 0
while index < len(fruit):
    answer = raw_input('Do you like %s? ' % fruit[index])
    if index > 0 and answer == 'back':
        inputs.pop()
        index -= 1
    else:
        inputs.append(answer)
        index += 1

print inputs
```